# Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Recently, I tried to update my app in AppStore. But it is rejected because of the following reasons.

> Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness
>
> Your app or its metadata does not appear to include final content.
>
> Specifically, in the screenshots.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please review your app and metadata to ensure
> that all of its content is final.
>
> Please see attached screenshots for details.
>
> Since your App Store Connect status is Metadata Rejected, we do NOT
> require a new binary. To revise the metadata, visit App Store Connect
> to select your app and revise the desired metadata values. Once you’ve
> completed all changes, reply to this message in Resolution Center and
> we will continue the review.

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]

**Update:**

Once after remove the test content from db. I replied to the review team as following:

> Kindly uninstall and re-install the app. We removed all sample data
> from DB. The above screenshot is not valid in the submitted build. We
> don't have such data in our DB.

Reply from review team:

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for your response.
>
> Regarding 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness - The screenshots are
> still to be found in your Metadata.
>
> To resolve this issue, please review your app and metadata to ensure
> that all of its content is final.
>
> Please see attached screenshots for details.
>
> Best regards,
>
> App Store Review

Comment: Here is the test data you need to remove this content and update with the perfect data.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because app store issues are generally considered off-topic. see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic) for more information

Comment: You need to remove "test shop 1" from the screen shot in your App Store connect metadata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your app (and the account you probably entered for Apple to login), but with your **screenshots**:

Any screenshots (and app previews for that matter) are not allowed to have "test", "beta", "alpha" etc. included in them. If you don't have the data in your database, simply download the existing screenshots, modify them with Photoshop, Sketch or a similar graphic program and re-upload them.

You could simply delete the text or replace it with some nicer sounding placeholder text/descriptions to give a good impression of your app with the screenshots.